# How to manage the Fitbit app permissions so messages don’t get processed?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, messages

The google fitbit app forwards all iOS imessages to the child's linked fitbit device (Fitbit Ace 3)

I believe this happens simply when  app notifcations are enabled.

I feel strongly App notifications should be notifications about that app and NOT randomly forwarding other messages to a separate device.

How do I block this behaviour where Fitbit app is siphoning all Messages into their system?

Comment: Go into your Fitbit app, select your device, go to notifications, then turn off "Calls" "Text Messages" and/or "Calendar Events"

Comment: I believe that the problem you have is off-topic, and I see no reason for you to complain to Apple

Comment: Let’s split the two very different questions - even asking two single questions that would be well received (get upvotes) together makes a question here less useful and prone to down votes. Please ask the [“how to report”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315365/how-to-report-app-developer-to-apple?rq=1) version of this as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

The quick solution to this is to turn off the various notifications on the FitBit app.  Your app may look slightly different to mine, as I have a Charge 4.

[image]

So that your child device doesn't show all notifications, simply turn off "Calls", "Text Messages", and/or "Calendar Events", along with going into "App Notifications" and turning off the ones you do not want.

Note: This answer covers the edited problem not that reporting may be in a separate thread. This is intended to cover the why and practical steps you can take now using the apps / OS that shipped.